# How to get 3D pose of a XAML UWP 2D Window on Hololens

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, augmented-reality, hololens

Is there a way to get the 3D pose of a XAML UWP 2D Window on Hololens ?

I searched the Windows.Perception namespace, but nothing conclusive.

It's easy to retrieve the position of the user's head and controllers. It's also easy to get the window height and width.

I would like to have a different interaction when the user is near or far from the window.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't get information about spatial position of a slate.

Comment: Is this intentional to prevent programs from doing anything with the position or is it something that will be supported in the API?
at the very least, is it possible to activate "follow me" by code?

Comment: It is intentional and I have no information about that could be changed in future. I think you need to try MRTK, it has set of primitives to make 2D slate from 3D app.